# How does an electron 'know' if a photon was emitted by a positively or negatively charged particle

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, electrons

I've always seen how electrons interact as being analogous to two particles passing a 'ball' between each other, thus exchanging momentum and repelling one and other.
This works for two particles of the same charge but doesn't for different ones.
Let's say we have some reasonably far-apart particles, an electron, and a positron.
The electron passes a photon to the positron, what happens is that the positron moves towards the electron, how does this work?
I would imagine that this 'ball' that was passed must've carried some information about where it came from, but then when I look up if photons emitted from positrons are the same as electrons, I see results saying that they are.

To put it in succinct terms:
Does the photon emitted by a charged particle carry any information about the charge of the object from which it originated?

Comment: Let me try to make a somewhat general comment. So obviously there are many ways a charged particle would result do something resulting in photon emission. Some of these ways include spontaneous emission, synchrotrons, stimulated emission, and so forth. In most or all of these ways the information one typically gets is something to do with the energy of the particle by way of the wavelength or frequency of the emitted photons. I don't know if it carries any more information than that.  My guess is that it does not know about the charge of the particle, just the energy.

Comment: Then how would another charged particle which absorbs or reflects this emitted photon be able to react differently depending on the source?

Comment: I don't know if it needs to know about the source.  It just needs to know some stuff about the "light". Stuff probably like its wavelength and polarization.

Comment: I'm not an expert though. So I could be wrong. We should wait for someone more experienced to comment or answer the question too.

Comment: @ Kevin Njokom
I had also thought about the polarity of the light coming into play somehow, but then again, this would imply that electrons can only emit photons of certain polarities, say for example only clockwise polarization, which I don't believe is true...

Comment: It knows because the interaction scales as a product of charges or, for more general interactions, currents. All talking about virtual photons does is switch us from the result Coulomb knew to a $k$-space integral, over such a product, that gives the phase of transition amplitudes in the path integral formulation. The “virtual particle” $4$-momentum is just the dummy integration variable. See e.g. _Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell_ Chapter I.V for details.

Comment: @J.G. Do you mean Chapter I.5 or chapter IV? I.5 is Coulomb and Newton: Repulsion and Attraction in my text

Comment: @J.G. Zee finds the propagator for the massive photon, then goes from there.  I think what he does next is just show that "The potential energy between two
lumps of charge density $J^0(x)$ is positive. The electromagnetic force between like charges is repulsive!" I don't know if that says anything about if they were both positive or both negative, just that if they are like they repel.

Comment: The key seems to be the negative sign one picks up comparing I.4.2 to I.5.5

Comment: @KevinNjokom You've found what's relevant. My point is the sesquilinear $J$-dependence of $W$, which is ultimately what the OP is asking about, is very Coulomb-like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real answer to your question, though legitimate because unfortunately it is based on a common misconception driven by pop science. All we can do is "debunk" this idea... Moreover, your last question is not clear because you do not explicitly say what kind of 'information' you think photons could carry apart from all their quantum numbers.

- Firstly, there is no exchange of virtual particles between two real particles. This is because, as I like to say, "virtual particles are mathematical artifacts from the perturbative expansion of the $S$ matrix we use." Roughly speaking, an $S$ matrix sends a "past infinity asymptotic state" to a "future infinity asymptotic state". We can write things like that:
  \begin{equation}
  |\psi(t\rightarrow \infty)\rangle = S|\psi(t\rightarrow -\infty) \rangle
  \end{equation}
  Then, since in QFT, we are interested in calculating the transition amplitudes, we project the state I've defined through the previous equation into another state, a final state arbitrarily chosen. So what is the probability amplitude for a state $|\psi_a \rangle$ to evolve into a state $|\psi_b\rangle$? The answer is:
  \begin{equation}
  A(|\psi_a\rangle \rightarrow |\psi_b\rangle)=\langle \psi_b | S | \psi_a \rangle
  \end{equation}
- Now, since in QED, the [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) is small compared to 1, we can expand the $S$ matrix (which is just an exponential) like $S = \text{Id}-iT+\cdots$. And we *define* the $\mathcal{M}_{ba}$ matrix elements to be:
  \begin{equation}
  \mathcal{M}_{ba}=\langle \psi_b | iT | \psi_a \rangle
  \end{equation}
  These transition amplitudes give us the Feynman rules, namely the elementary blocks of Feynman diagrams. Thus, Feynman diagrams are mathematical tools representing transition amplitudes.

Going back to your question, you can see that I've never talked about virtual particles because these turn out to simply be internal lines of Feynman diagrams. Thus they are mathematical artifacts from the perturbative expansion of the $S$ matrix we use, as I said above.

Note that in general, we use the momentum representation, so our Feynman diagrams are nice products of algebraic quantities. But in position representations, they are *convolutions*, which is harder to deal with, taking into account the horrible expression for the propagators in position space (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator)), even though it is much simpler for massless particles

---

Now, your question was along the line of "how come charged particles attract in one case and repel in the other case?". This is simply... The Coulomb Law. One can show that in position representation, our tree-level Feynman diagrams (diagrams not involving loops of propagators) for the $e^- e^+$ and $e^- e^-$ scattering reduce to the Coulomb Law$^{1}$ if we approximate the electron/positron field as having only two static Dirac delta-shaped particles$^{2}$. The higher-order diagrams contribute to the quantum corrections of the Coulomb law, making us able to derive such things as the [Uehling potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uehling_potential#:%7E:text=In%20quantum%20electrodynamics%2C%20the%20Uehling,Edwin%20Albrecht%20Uehling%20in%201935.) for example.

In conclusion, your question is completely legitimate, and this is why it has been upvoted. But it is unfortunately based on a misconception, and as you can see from what I have written, things are much more complex than just "balls exchanged between particles". Instead, you have to see particle fields as interacting through what we call "gauge fields" (in our case, the photon field). And so the picture is not that different from the usual one of an electromagnetic field influenced by the presence of charged particles, except that in our case, we are able to compute quantum corrections.

[1] More precisely, you simply have to convolve your charge distribution with the propagator to find the photon field in the presence of this charge distribution, and then it is straightforward to find the potential energy associated with another charge distribution in this very photon field.

[2] Why static? Because then you are able to calculate the classical force between the particles and say that if you let them move, they will attract or repel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, just to answer something you brought up in your response: You mention that I don't make it clear what kind of information a photon could carry, and you are right, this is because I really don't know myself.
And although probably silly or based on a total lack of knowledge relating to the field, as an example, I could postulate that each photon carries some sort of 'flag' that specifies if it were from a positive or negative particle. Just to show what I meant by information carried by the photon.

Answer (score 1):

The common YouTube passing the ball analogy for virtual photon exchange has done more harm than good. This is a common question that arises from the analogy that does really shed any light on scattering in QED, and encourages people to think of virtual particles in a far too classical context.

One way to look at it is to compare Bhabha scattering (electron-positron) and Moeller scattering (electron-electron) in the 1-photon exchange cross section. The scattering probability goes as an amplitude ($|-iM|$) squared, where Feynman diagrams are used to compute the amplitude. The amplitudes are proportion to the charge squared, so you don't even see the sign of the charge in the amplitude. Any difference comes in in the structure of the Dirac spinors (since anti-matter is different from matter).

I chose these reaction because their wikipedia pages shows their explicit calculations.

In Moller scattering you have:

[image]

where the photon has "mass" $t$. Since electrons are indistinguishable, there is a term with mass $u$:

[image]

They are added coherently and squared to get (in the relativistic limit) something that looks like:

$$ e^4\Big(\frac{s^2+u^2}{t^2} + \frac{s^2}{tu} +
\frac{s^2+t^2}{u^2}
\Big)$$

Meanwhile, in Bhabha scattering, there is an annihilation term:

[image]

which photon "mass" $s$, and a scattering term, again with $t$:

[image]

The probability goes like:

$$ e^4\Big(\frac{s^2+u^2}{t^2} + \frac{u^2}{st} +
\frac{s^2+t^2}{u^2}
\Big)$$

No sign of the sign of the charge, though there are remarkable symmetries in the formulae.

Regarding whether a virtual particle transmits information, they save answer is: No. One reason is $t < 0$ in the t-channel, meaning the exchanged photon in scattering is space like: the vertices cannot be time ordered. (Analogy: the basket ball is exchanged between the boats at faster than the speed of light....so it can't exchange information).

In the s-channel (annihilation), the photon is time-like but it seems to erase the information, where information means "charge and other quantum numbers that cancel between matter/anti matter pairs". Since it doesn't need to turn back into electron/positrons, it could be $q\bar q$ or $\mu^+\mu^-$..., that electron information is lost.

Basically: virtual particles bookkeep the energy, momentum, spin, charge, and other quantum numbers, in order to calculate a term in an infinite series approximation of the process.

In the

Comment: While I thank you for the answer, besides the mathematical representation is there any way of describing this in more physical terms?
Also, I'm not completely speaking of virtual photons either, for example, what if the particles are far enough apart such that no virtual particle could be transmitted, instead only a real photon?

And again I appreciate the answer, but the math does not particularly answer my question, which is if the photon itself carries any information.

Comment: @NaiDoeShacks What do you mean by far enough not to exchange a virtual particle? If they are interacting electromagnetically they always will do so the probability will just be suppressed! So talking about one without the other is kind of hard. If you actually only want real photons you are kind of throwing away the electromagnetic interaction of the two particles in which case the charge does not matter. I.e. only the momentum exchange is accounted for.

Comment: @NaiDoeShacks The virtual particle is a thing that describes the math (in a very formal way). The particle being the "physical terms" you request; however, it is unphysical, and thinking of it too classically doesn't elucidate anything. Nevertheless, there are terms like "highly virtual", and virtual particles approach being real when $t\rightarrow 0$, which is in the limit nothing happens.

Comment: @NaiDoeShacks re information, see edits

Comment: I'm sorry, my impression was that a virtual particle is a particle that exists for a short enough time such that it could never be measured, which is why I said 'far enough apart such that a virtual particle could not be exchanged', what I meant was that the distance it would have to traverse would be large enough that it would have to exist for a long enough time so that it could be measured.

By reading all of the answers given here I have come to the conclusion that my intuition of quantum mechanics was wrong.

Comment: That intuition was that all particles are the lowest possible excitation in their respective fields, whose aspects are probabilistic.
The particle propagates in accordance with its wave function and when interacting with other particles its actions on them appear to be very localized or point-like, not in the likeness of the wave function.

I had thought that the emitted photons by electrons and other charged particles were the force carriers of the electromagnetic force and that virtual particles were simply short-lived versions of these.

Comment: @NaiDoeShacks So the "exists for a short time and borrows energy" virtual particle view was passé in 1948. Now they conserve everything at all vertices, and time really isn't a thing for them. They are a approximations of the field configurations in going from the initial state to the final state.

Comment: @NaiDoeShacks It's not quantum mechanics, it's (relativistic) quantum field theory...a subject not known for submitting to intuition.